# adding a device to another device in a raid config

Tags: linux

If I have a device mounted in RHEL, how do I add another device to it and make it a raid0 config?

I know how to mount two new devices in a raid0 config, but how do I do it with one device that is already in use and has data on it?

Comment: [so] is about programming; for general computing questions, please consider migrating your question to [su] or [Unix & linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com)

Comment: please do not add a bounty just to prevent an off-topic question from being migrated/closed. If you are really interested in getting an answer to your question, allow it to be migrated to the correct community for a quick and accurate response.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the details; is it an lvm volume? Then add the new device to the volume group and extend the logical volume. Is it a file system like ZFS? Then add the device to the pool. Otherwise, you need to backup the mounted drive, unmount and create a raid0 volume.

Answer (score -1):

Save you some headaches and clone the drive with a disk imaging software like Clonezilla (http://clonezilla.org/).

Once you have your drived cloned as a disk image, set up RAID0 and recover your clone to the newly created RAID, telling Clonezilla to expand to the total size of the disk.

This way, even if something goes wrong, you can always undo the whole process and just recover your clone into the original single disk as if nothing happened.

Hope it helps,

Regards

Comment: For all the haters downvoting valid answers in this post: If you want to express your disconformity with the question, just downvote the question. Do not downvote valid answers from people who tries to help. Retards.

Comment: People can vote how ever they want. If you don't like it, don't post answers on blatantly off-topic questions.

Comment: .@e.lopez No need to be that rude, especially if you're being told how things are supposed to work here and you're a newbie. Whether your answer is valid or not, **the question is off-topic**, and should not exist here. Answers are not useful if they feed bad questions. You should take a look at [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow).

Comment: I'm not being rude, just accordingly reacting to other's rudeness. And by the way, I don't appreciate my comments getting removed.

Comment: And if the question is off-topic, just remove it for god's sake. And lets stop wasting our time in this nonsense conversation...

Comment: @black I read the interesting question you linked and I guess I understand now a bit more the reaction regarding this topic. Thanks for sharing it, I guess I agree with the fact that we all should contribute so that SO remains a source of quality questions and answers. Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible. You can't have a mounted drive and convert it into a RAID array along with another drive. You will surely have to unmount it first. More realistically, you'll probably have to reformat the drive before adding it to a RAID array. Understand that the RAID is being managed at a lower level than the OS. The OS sees the RAID array as one partition. The OS has no ability to manage or add drives to an existing RAID array.